# reading a "\n" string and writing to textfile?

Tags: c++, string, escaping

I'm struggling with the following: I'm reading from an XML file the following std::stringstream

```
"sigma=0\nreset"
```

Which after some copying&processing is written to a text-file. And I was hoping for the following

```
sigma=0
reset
```

But sadly I only get

```
sigma=0\nreset
```

but when I directly stream

```
out << "sigma=0\nreset"
```

I get:

```
sigma=0
reset
```

I currently suspect that some qualifier of the "\n" is lost during the "copy&processing"... is this possible? How to track down a "\n" in the stream which isn't a linefeed anymore?

Thank you!

Comment: It's unlikely that anything replaced `'\n'` with `"\\n"`, could you verify the string just after reading and just before writing, and show your output code?

Comment: Does the xml file contain a newline, or the `\\` character followed by an `n` character?

Answer (score 3):

It's because the output functions doesn't handle the escape sequences like `'\n'`, it's the compiler that does and then only for literals. The compiler knows nothing of the contents of strings, and so can not do the translation `"\n"` to newline when inside a string.

You have to parse the string itself, and write out newlines when appropriate.

Comment: there is no translation `'\n'` to newline, unless I misunderstand you. `'\n'` _is_ a newline.

Comment: @Useless Clarified that a little.

Comment: Yeah, I was assuming the string read in was _identical_ to the literal `"sigma=0\nreset"`, but now I'm not so sure ...

Comment: @Useless: I don't think it was.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the `std::stringstream` actually contains what is equivalent to the literal `"sigma=0\\nreset"` (length = 14 characters) and not `"sigma=0\nreset"` (length = 13 characters), you'll have to replace it yourself. Doing so is not very difficult, either use boost's `replace_all`  (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/replace_all.html), or `std::string::find` and `std::string::replace`:

```
std::stringstream inStream;
inStream.str ("sigma=0\\nreset");
std::string content = inStream.str();

size_t index = content.find("\\n",0);

while(index != std::string::npos)
{
   content.replace(index, 2, "\n");
   index = content.find("\\n",index);
}

std::cout << content << '\n';
```

Note: you may want to consider cases when the system end-of-line is something other than `"\n"`

If the `std::stringstream` actually contains `"sigma=0\nreset"`, then please post the code that does the copying/processing and the writing to the text file.